# appended html tag not getting back using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
while(perpage>=curr){
            var item = getDataBackOut[curr];
            $("#main_body ul").append("<li><a href='#' id='more'>showmore</a><div id='gred'><a href="+item.productUrl+"><img alt='prasad' src="+item.productImageUrl+"><p id='para'>"+item.productDescription+"</p></a></div></li>");
            curr++;
        }
```

this values coming from database iam using JSON object. after diplaying list items iam trying to click showmore but that event is not occurred any help/

Comment: id should be unique and `dynamic content` => `event delegation`

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should be unique so use `class` instead

```
while(perpage>=curr){
    var item = getDataBackOut[curr];
    $("#main_body ul").append("<li><a href='#' class='more'>showmore</a><div id='gred'><a href="+item.productUrl+"><img alt='prasad' src="+item.productImageUrl+"><p id='para'>"+item.productDescription+"</p></a></div></li>");
    //...........................................^.............................
    curr++;
}
```

Then you need to use [**`event delegation`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method , since the list item is created dynamically

```
$("#main_body ul").on('click','.more',function(){ 
     //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use event delegation, since this is dynamically added to DOM.

```
 $("#main_body ul").on('click','#more' ,function(){
    //your logic
  })
```

And ID should be unique